# C# Windows Application SharePoint Login

Tags: c#, sharepoint

```
string urlSite = "https://intranet.site.dk";
string user = "myuser@vid.net.local";
string pwd = "mypass";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(urlSite))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm trying to login on a sharepoint web site.
This code is what i could come up with.
No matter what i do, i'll get the Not authorized (401)
But if i type the exactly same in my browser, it's working fine..
Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your code simple ;) use this codes:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(urlSite))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain);
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```