# Unable to Pass Authentication Credentials to Client Object Model C# using Share Point 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to pass credentials to my Client Object Model using .NET C#. I am working with Share Point 2013 and using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`.

I have tried many different iterations but I still keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` error. However - if I sign into the site URL via the browser - I am able to login no problem - meaning I do have access to the site. Below is the method I used - as well as the code updates. If someone can please take a look and explain or show me how to do this properly I would be greatly appreciative!

---

**Authentication()**

```
    public static ClientContext Authentication()
    {
        //Take 1:
        NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userNameFixed, passwordFixed,"https://CLARITYCON/");


        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

        clientContext.Credentials = _myCredentials;

        return clientContext;

        //Take 2:
        //ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);


        //SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

        //foreach (char c in passwordFixed.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        //clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userNameFixed, passWord);

        //try
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Working!");
        //    return clientContext;
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(e);
        //    return null;
        //}

        // Take 3:
        //using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
        //{
        //    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

        //    foreach (char c in passwordFixed.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

        //    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userNameFixed, passWord);

        //    try
        //    {
        //        return clientContext;
        //    }

        //    catch (Exception e)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine(e);
        //        return null;
        //    }

        //}


    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have also added the method that I am calling - the `Authentication()`.

**DeleteAFile()**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Will list out all the items within a Site, conduct a search and delete the item when found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <param name="sFldrLoc"></param>
    private static void DeleteAFile(string sFileName, string sFldrLoc)
    {

      var clientContext = Authentication();

        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection collList = web.Lists;

        List oList = collList.GetByTitle(sFldrLoc);

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Leq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>100</Value>" +
            "</Leq></Where></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>";

        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(query);

        clientContext.Load(collListItem,
            items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                item => item.DisplayName));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


        foreach (ListItem listitem in collListItem)
        {
            if (listitem.DisplayName.Equals(sFileName))
            {
                listitem.DeleteObject();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("{0}, has been deleted sucessfully!", listitem.DisplayName);
            }

        }
    }
```

The commented code are all the versions of code that I have tired to implement. All are returning a `401 Unauthorized` error.

Answer (score 0):

You most pass the your domain in last parameter not your Sharepoint URL

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userNameFixed, passwordFixed,"https://CLARITYCON/");
```

If "CLARITYCON" is your domain not your Sharepoint URL your most remove HTTPS like this code:

```
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userNameFixed, passwordFixed,"CLARITYCON");
```

domain in this code is **DomainName**\UserName

Comment: I am still getting a `401` error - when I try `https://CLARITYCON/` or "CLARITYCON"

Comment: is realy CLARITYCON your domain server name? see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424603/c-sharp-windows-application-sharepoint-login/36425062#36425062 I think you have a problem with correct parameters